# R reverts to 8.3 FAT file naming, package install fails

Tags: r, cran

Folks:

I have a strange one here. Something changed in my environment (corporate managed) where package installation is failing. What appears to be happening is the old DOS FAT 8.3 file naming scheme is popping in on this NTFS drive.  I've reset the environment variables inside R, and I can't figure out where this ~1 naming stuff is coming from. The error is bolded below.

Has anyone had something like this?

Here's the output:

> install.packages("tidyr")
>
> Installing package into ‘H:/Fileset for me/My Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> There is a binary version available but the source version is
>     later:
>         binary source needs_compilation
>   tidyr  0.2.0  0.3.0             FALSE
>
> installing the source package ‘tidyr’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyr_0.3.0.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150414 bytes (146 KB)
>   downloaded 146 KB
>
> **'H:\FILES~6XF\MYDO~' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   The system cannot find the path specified.**
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"H:/Fileset for Me/My Documents/R/R-3.2.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "H:\Fileset for Me\My Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\TEMP\RtmpEPtflD/downloaded_packages/tidyr_0.3.0.tar.gz' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘tidyr’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>           ‘C:\Temp\RtmpEPtflD\downloaded_packages’